# Watir Set value of input type="text"

Tags: ruby, watir

I am trying to set an email into this span but I'm having trouble selecting it and updating it. The span id is created dynamically but the class is not

```
<div class="input input-lg    form-input">

    <span id="foundation-text-input-3535" class="input-label ">Email*</span>

    <input type="text" aria-labelledby="foundation-text-input-3535" placeholder="" value="" autocomplete="off" data-qa="email_input"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be getting set via the input element, not the span, right?

```
browser.text_field(data_qa: 'email_input').set email_address
```

You can also use regular expressions as well if you need to locate things that way:

```
browser.span(id: /foundation-text-input/)
```

Results from irb:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'watir'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> browser = Watir::Browser.new
=> #<Watir::Browser:0x6e1ac1ec79323ad4 url="data:," title="">
irb(main):003:0> browser.goto "https://portal.sysco.com/login"
=> "https://portal.sysco.com/login"
irb(main):004:0> browser.text_field(data_qa: 'email_input').set "test"
=> nil
irb(main):005:0> browser.text_field(data_qa: 'email_input').value
=> "test"
```

Comment: I'm getting #<Watir::TextField: located: false; {:data_qa=>"email_input", :tag_name=>"input"}> trying to locate that element.  wonder if something else is going on with this page

Comment: https://portal.sysco.com/login is the address if you're up for trying

Comment: it doesn't locate it by default when you define it, only when you use it. This will show you it's been located: `browser.text_field(data_qa: 'email_input').tap(&:present?)`

Comment: that's good to know! thank you.  I am still getting a timeout error , waiting for true condition when I run browser.text_field(data_qa: 'email_input').set "test"

Comment: I updated the answer with the log of what I just executed. It seems to be working fine for me.

Comment: and you solved it, thank you!